# Difference between Android sensors's sampling rates

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope, magnetometer

I am trying to write accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer sensor values into txt file. I wrote this sensor values into different files. But I realized that when I give sensors's delay to *fastest*, accelerometer and gyroscope sensors had same number of samplings but, unlike them, magnetometer sensor has almost half of number samplings. Then I tried all of sensors delay number to *200000 ms* and their sampling number was almost same. I want to know why this difference is caused. I am new to Android and sensors so a little help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

```
     if(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            x_axis = event.values[0];
            y_axis = event.values[1];
            z_axis = event.values[2];

            try {
                writeToFile("accelerometer.txt", letter + " " + subject + " " + timestamp + " " + x_axis + " " + y_axis + " " + z_axis + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {

            gyro_x_axis = event.values[0];
            gyro_y_axis = event.values[1];
            gyro_z_axis = event.values[2];

            try {
                writeToFile("gyroscope.txt", letter + " " + subject + " " + timestamp + " " + gyro_x_axis + " " + gyro_y_axis + " " + gyro_z_axis + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            mag_x_axis = event.values[0];
            mag_y_axis = event.values[1];
            mag_z_axis = event.values[2];

            try {
                writeToFile("magnetometer.txt", letter + " " + subject + " " + timestamp + " " + mag_x_axis + " " + mag_y_axis + " " + mag_z_axis + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please try to make your question more specific.  Are you trying to understand why magnetometer produces fewer samples? Or are you asking how to poll all sensors at the fastest rate that provides samples from each sensor?  Or something else?.   Provide some code and sample output demonstrating the problem, if possible.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I made some additions in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sensors are physical devices.  That means they all respond to inputs at different rates.  For example, the accelerometer sensor may be able to detect a change in 2ms, and the light sensor may take 100ms.  So you have two choices-  either sample at the rate of the slowest sensor on the device (in which case you lose 98% of the data from the accelerometer in this example) or have each sensor have a different sampling rate for FASTEST.  Android chose the second, because otherwise you'd lose a lot of valuable data.

What FASTEST is for each device and sensor will vary-  different devices will have different implementations of sensors that work in different ways.

Comment: thank you for answering. Now I understand that it is normal to have different number of sampling. I want to ask one more thing, I will use this values in gesture recognition so Will I need to make them same sampling length? If so Should I fill in the blank spaces with zero?

Comment: Definitely don't use 0.  More correct would be to use the last value until you get a new one.

Comment: Sorry, I know that I am asking too many questions but how can I do what you are saying? The one with until new value thing?